# how do I get the list of users who liked post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [this](https://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/wordpress-post-like-system/) post like system in my wordpress theme and I want to display usernames who liked the post in single page , in database post meta is like this ;

```
post_id: 22
meta_key: _user_liked 
value: a:2:{s:6:"user-2";i:2;s:6:"user-1";i:1;}
```

tried this code ;

```
<?php $userlikes = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , '_user_liked', true );
$returnValue = unserialize($userlikes[0]);
echo $returnValue; ?>
```

thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

This is a **serialised data**:

```
value: a:2:{s:6:"user-2";i:2;s:6:"user-1";i:1;}
```

You need to [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it:

```
$returnValue = unserialize('a:2:{s:6:"user-2";i:2;s:6:"user-1";i:1;}');
```

Which gives you:

```
array (
  'user-2' => 2,
  'user-1' => 1,
)
```

[**Online Demo**](https://en.functions-online.com/unserialize.html?command=%7B"str":"a:2:%7Bs:6:%5C"user-2%5C";i:2;s:6:%5C"user-1%5C";i:1;%7D"%7D)

Comment: I tried this but not working ,

    <?php $userlikes = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() , '_user_liked', true );

    $returnValue = unserialize($userlikes[0]);
    echo $returnValue;
     ?>